# Bar chart values are overlapped, slice is very small to show these values

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\caption{Existing Scenario:
Mode Wise Percentage Share}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{
    width=8cm,  height=6cm,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,         
    % <---
    xtick style = {draw=none},          % <---
    x tick label style={yshift=-2.2em},   % <---
    ytick={0,20,...,200},    
    ylabel=label,
% coordinates
    xtick distance=1,
    symbolic x coords={KAR-MMK, MMK-MCK, MCK-TJB}, yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
    ymin=0, ymax=200,  
    ybar stacked,
    axis on top,                        % <---
% nodes 
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\footnotesize,rotate=90}, % <--- modified
    stacked ignores zero=false,
    nnc_ticklabels/.style={ % <-- new style
       point meta=explicit symbolic,
       every node near coord/.style={
          font=\footnotesize, below,
          rotate=40,
          anchor=north east, % <- changed from east
          inner sep=1pt % <- added
          }
       }
    % <===
            }
%%%% diagram body
\begin{axis}[ylabel=Percentage Share,bar width=8pt, 
             bar shift=-15pt]
\addplot [xshift=-15pt, nnc_ticklabels] coordinates % <-- added the new style for all the "ticklabel" plots
    {(KAR-MMK,0) [Road]
     (MMK-MCK,0) [Road]
     (MCK-TJB,0) [Road]
    };

\addplot [fill=none,mark=Black,postaction={pattern=north east lines}] 
coordinates {(KAR-MMK,69) (MMK-MCK,28) (MCK-TJB,28)};
\addplot [fill=none,mark=Black,postaction={pattern=dots}]
coordinates {(KAR-MMK,98) (MMK-MCK,98) (MCK-TJB,43)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ylabel=Percentage Share,
             bar width=8pt,
             bar shift=-5pt]
\addplot  [xshift=-5pt, nnc_ticklabels] coordinates
    {(KAR-MMK,0) [Railway]
     (MMK-MCK,0) [Railway]
     (MCK-TJB,0) [Railway]
    };
\addplot [fill=none,mark=Black,postaction={pattern=north east lines}]   coordinates {(KAR-MMK,052) (MMK-MCK,28) (MCK-TJB,02)};
\addplot[fill=none,mark=Black,postaction={pattern=dots}] coordinates {(KAR-MMK,30) (MMK-MCK,2) (MCK-TJB,02)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ylabel=Percentage Share,
             bar width=8pt,
             bar shift=5pt]
\addplot [xshift=5pt, nnc_ticklabels] coordinates
    {(KAR-MMK,0) [Pipeline]
     (MMK-MCK,0) [Pipeline]
     (MCK-TJB,0) [Pipeline]
    };
\addplot [fill=none,mark=Black,postaction={pattern=north east lines}]  
coordinates {(KAR-MMK,42) (MMK-MCK,25) (MCK-TJB,33)};
\legend {,HSD,MS},
\addplot [fill=none,mark=Black,postaction={pattern=dots}]
coordinates {(KAR-MMK,39) (MMK-MCK,48) (MCK-TJB,47)};
   
        ]
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To append percent signs to the labels, you can use `nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\,\%}`. Note that if you add this to the axis, it will also be applied to the labels of the plot that you added to add the labels for "Road", "Railway" and "Pipeline". Therefore, you would need to reset the option for these labels to the default `nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}`.

In order to align those labels where the box size is too small, you can use the option `coordinate style/.condition` and use conditional expressions to only select the relevant label which you can then assign specific styles. I am unsure whether the solution for the second bar in the third group is optimal, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{
    width=8cm,
    height=6cm,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,         
    xtick style={draw=none},
    x tick label style={yshift=-2.2em}, 
    ytick={0,20,...,200},    
    ylabel=label,
% coordinates
    xtick distance=1,
    symbolic x coords={KAR-MMK, MMK-MCK, MCK-TJB}, yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
    ymin=0, 
    ymax=200,  
    ybar stacked,
    axis on top,   
% nodes 
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\,\%},
    every node near coord/.append style={
        font=\scriptsize,
        rotate=90
    },
    stacked ignores zero=false,
    nnc_ticklabels/.style={
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
        every node near coord/.style={
            font=\scriptsize, 
            below,
            rotate=40,
            anchor=north east, 
            inner sep=1pt,
        }
    },
    coordinate style/.condition={\coordindex == 1 && y > 28 && y <= 30}{
        right
    },
    coordinate style/.condition={\coordindex == 2 && y > 0 && y <= 2}{
        right
    },
    coordinate style/.condition={\coordindex == 2 && y > 2 && y <= 4}{
        right, yshift=.5cm
    }
}
%%%% diagram body
\begin{axis}[ylabel=Percentage Share,
    bar width=8pt, 
    bar shift=-15pt]
\addplot [xshift=-15pt, nnc_ticklabels] coordinates 
    {(KAR-MMK,0) [Road]
     (MMK-MCK,0) [Road]
     (MCK-TJB,0) [Road]
    };
\addplot [fill=none, mark=Black, postaction={pattern=north east lines, pattern color=lightgray}] 
coordinates {(KAR-MMK,69) (MMK-MCK,28) (MCK-TJB,28)};
\addplot [fill=none, mark=Black, postaction={pattern=dots}]
coordinates {(KAR-MMK,98) (MMK-MCK,98) (MCK-TJB,43)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ylabel=Percentage Share,
             bar width=8pt,
             bar shift=-5pt]
\addplot [xshift=-5pt, nnc_ticklabels] coordinates
    {(KAR-MMK,0) [Railway]
     (MMK-MCK,0) [Railway]
     (MCK-TJB,0) [Railway]
    };
\addplot [fill=none, mark=Black, postaction={pattern=north east lines, pattern color=lightgray}] coordinates {(KAR-MMK,52) (MMK-MCK,28) (MCK-TJB,2)};
\addplot [fill=none, mark=Black, postaction={pattern=dots}] coordinates {(KAR-MMK,30) (MMK-MCK,2) (MCK-TJB,2)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ylabel=Percentage Share,
             bar width=8pt,
             bar shift=5pt]
\addplot [xshift=5pt, nnc_ticklabels] coordinates
    {(KAR-MMK,0) [Pipeline]
     (MMK-MCK,0) [Pipeline]
     (MCK-TJB,0) [Pipeline]
    };
\addplot [fill=none, mark=Black, postaction={pattern=north east lines, pattern color=lightgray}]  
coordinates {(KAR-MMK,42) (MMK-MCK,25) (MCK-TJB,33)};
\addplot [fill=none, mark=Black, postaction={pattern=dots}]
coordinates {(KAR-MMK,39) (MMK-MCK,48) (MCK-TJB,47)};

\legend {,HSD,MS}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Loved it stay blessed